# Проблема при мёрдже

Tags: git, git-merge

Делаю вот такое действие из моей ветки `my-branch`

```
git merge origin/master
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов есть сайд эффекты какие-нибудь?

Comment: Нет, только прямые - у вас будет 2 начальных коммита, от которых до мержа тянутся независимые истории. Иногда это очень полезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема следующая. Был создан репозиторий, в котором изначально не было ветки `origin/master`. После этого она там появилась. Например, после `git fetch`. Также было сделано несколько коммитов для `my-branch`. Проблема заключается в том, что у этих двух веток разные истории. Как следствие -- разные первые коммиты. Фактические два разных репозитория.

Следует удалить папку `.git`, сначала сделать `git fetch`, а только после этого создавать дополнительные ветки.